# Makefile wxWidgets

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets

Estou tentando utilizar o wxWidgets para fazer um projeto da faculdade e acabei tentando usar o Makefile por curiosidade, abaixo o makefile que estou usando como exemplo para o projeto.

Makefile

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
LD_FLAGS := -lm
CPP_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra


Crypto: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LD_FLAGS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h
    g++ $(CPP_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) *.o
```

Eu tentei adaptar ele pra usar as flags e libs do wxWidgets porém quando eu executo o makefile ele me da alguns erros de linker...

Makefile wxWidgets

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
# wx-config --libs
WX_LIBS = $(shell wx-config --libs)
# wx-config --cxxflags
WX_CXXFLAGS = $(shell wx-config --cxxflags) 
LD_FLAGS := -lm
CPP_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra

Crypto: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LD_FLAGS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h
    g++ $(CPP_FLAGS) $(WX_CXXFLAGS) $(WX_LIBS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) *.o
```

Um dos erros de linker que é gerado

```
mainWindow.cpp:(.text._ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EclEPS3_RS4_[_ZN20wxEventFunctorMethodI14wxEventTypeTagI14wxCommandEventE12wxEvtHandler7wxEventS3_EclEPS3_RS4_]+0x8c): undefined reference to `wxTrap()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

O que eu posso modificar nesse makefile? Ainda estou estudando o funcionamento do makefile e estou tentando aplicar ele usando o wxWidgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trecho do seu Makefile:

```
Crypto: $(OBJ_FILES)         # Faz a lincagem
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LD_FLAGS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp src/%.h   # Compila arquivos individuais
    g++ $(CPP_FLAGS) $(WX_CXXFLAGS) $(WX_LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

Na variável `WX_LIBS` estão guardadas as flags para fazer a lincagem com o WxWidgets, então precisa passar isso no momento de fazer a lincagem, não na compilação.

Outro ponto: para fazer apenas a compilação e gerar um arquivo .o, como é sua intensão no segundo bloco ali, precisa passar a flag `-c` para o gcc, caso contrário ele tentará gerar um executável imediatamente, só com aquele arquivo.